# How to get sbt-assembly merge right?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra

In our Scala/Scalatra project, we have this merge policy for the plugin `sbt-assembly`:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case x =>
   val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
   oldStrategy(x)
}
```

> [error] 11 errors were encountered during merge
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
>   ~/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatra/scalatra_2.11/jars/scalatra_2.11-2.3.1.jar:mime.types
>   ~/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/jars/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.1.jar:mime.types
>
> deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
>   ~/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.class
>   ~/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.class
>   deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
>
> and the same error for different class names

What would be the right merge logic here?

Versions:

Scala       : 2.11.7
SBT         : 0.13.9
sbt-assembly: 0.13.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original issue was solved with:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org", "apache", "commons", "collections", xs @ _*) =>
      MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("mime.types") =>
      MergeStrategy.last
  case x =>
      val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
      oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not think, it is a matter of "merge-strategy", but more of the libs and their dependencies you are using.

Who "pulls" these dependencies? Which libraries are you using concretely?

One way to restrict is to use `excludeAll` (and similar) with dependency declaration. (see [library management in SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html) ), e.g.

```
excludeAll(
  ExclusionRule("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core"),
  ExclusionRule("commons-collections", "commons-collections"),
  ExclusionRule("commons-logging", "commons-logging"),
  ExclusionRule("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
  ExclusionRule("org.hamcrest", "hamcrest-core"),
  ExclusionRule("junit", "junit"),
  ExclusionRule("org.jboss.netty", "netty"),
  ExclusionRule("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog")
  )
```