# Maven Assembly Plugin Merge Strategy

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to convert a Scala/Java project build from sbt to Maven.  I have gotten the project running with no issues except when trying to package the fat jar.

I am running into some problems when trying to write a merge strategy.  Here is the code I am trying to convert, from build.sbt:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", "MANIFEST.MF")  => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*)        => MergeStrategy.first
  case x                                    => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

I am trying to use Maven's assembly plugin with a custom descriptor.  I have been playing around with the container descriptor handlers provided, but none of them are merging like sbt does.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
<id>my-project</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>

<containerDescriptorHandlers>
    <containerDescriptorHandler>
        <handlerName>metaInf-services</handlerName>
    </containerDescriptorHandler>
    <containerDescriptorHandler>
        <handlerName>metaInf-spring</handlerName>
    </containerDescriptorHandler>
    <containerDescriptorHandler>
        <handlerName>plexus</handlerName>
    </containerDescriptorHandler>
</containerDescriptorHandlers>
```

Is there any way to mock the MergeStrategy from the sbt build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my "adventure" on [migrating assembly from Maven to SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249818/why-maven-assembly-works-when-sbt-assembly-find-conflicts) I think I have touched a similar ground and I can provide some insight.

### You can either, or both:

- read the answers in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249818/why-maven-assembly-works-when-sbt-assembly-find-conflicts)
- check out my [github project](https://github.com/atais/mvn-sbt-assembly) which digs this topic

### The summary

Since the only `sbt assembly` `MergeStrategy` you should be worried about is `MergeStrategy.first` your maven build should be fine because it is the **default** setting in Maven. The jar will have different content but it will function the same.

Unless I am missing something, then please provide more detailed info.